# Is pynput capped at how fast it can run?

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

For example, with pyautogui, you can allow it to go as fast as you want with pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

Is there something similar for pynput? (Allow it to run as fast as my computer lets it?)

Answer (score 1):

well I think not but u could theoretically try messing with while cycle so it would just press and release the mouse button (if it wont register the clicks u could try to import time and experiment which is the minimal delay of seconds to register those clicks)
it would look like something this:

```
    while True:
        mouse.press(Button.right)
        time.sleep(0.001) #experiment with this number and see which works best
        mouse.release(Button.right)
```